Include doesn't get the related entity
It's the first time my .Include() doesn't return the entity. I don't know what is missing.
Billings class
public Order Order { get; set; }
public List<BillingItem>? BillingItems { get; set; }

ApplicationDbContext:
modelBuilder.Entity<Billing>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Order)
            .WithOne(e => e.Billing)
            .HasForeignKey<Billing>(e => e.OrderID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

Execution watch variable

Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images. They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines.

For inserting a new item where one doesn't already exist:

var billing await db.Billings
    .Include(b => b.Order)
    .ThenInclude(o => o.OrderItems)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsnc(b => b.OrderId == orderId && b.Status != Status.Deleted);

if(billing != null)
{
    billing = new Billing();
    order = await db.Orders
        .Include(o => o.OrderItems)
        .SingleAsync(o => o.Id == orderId && o.Status != Status.Deleted);
   billing.CreateFromOrder(order);
   db.Billings.Add(billing);
   await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}

Fetch the existing billing with associated Order/OrderItems at the start. If we don't find one, create one, fetching the Order /w OrderItems, and associating that to the new billing, then Add() the billing before saving.
We don't need to attempt to reload the billing after inserting, we can fetch any existing billing at the start. Importantly use DbSet.Add() not Attach() to ensure EF knows this is a new Billing. Attach() is only used when dealing with detached, existing entities we want to ensure the DbContext treats as existing rows. For inserts we use tracking queries for any entities we want to associate (Order/OrderItems).
If we just wanted to check if a billing does not exist then we don't need to load it, we can just do an exists check /w .Any():
var billingExists db.Billings
    .Any(b => b.OrderId == orderId && b.Status != Status.Deleted);

if(billing != null)
{
    Billing billing = new Billing();
    ...

One important change I highly recommend to avoid errors when it comes to navigation properties is wherever you have collection navigation properties such as Order.OrderItems you should not have an accessible setter. For instance code like order.OrderItems = orderItems is very bad as the change tracker will have had a proxy in place to notice when collection items are added/removed and when you re-assign a collection, that proxy is blasted.
Instead of:
public ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }

Collection navigation properties should be declared as:
public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; } = [];
// or
public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; protected set; } = new List<OrderItem>(); // for older C# versions.

No code should ever set a collection navigation property after it is initialized.

so i'm still working on this page, but basically, sometimes there's already a billing, sometimes not. I'm either passing a orderId to clone (and then modify if needed) or a billingid
so at this moment, the billing exist, and doesn't go to the creating, that's why i have to fetch it. i definitely need to remove the fetch after creation, but it's not the case i'm testing right now
For some reason, and maybe you can explain to me, the oninit is gone through twice for each page. so right now, it fetches if i have a billingid, twice, or if not, it create than fetches anyways on 2nd pass

"the oninit is gone through twice for each page" - search that first and find some answers about pre-rendering.

OnInitializedAsync is called twice in blazor, once for pre-rendering. So performing data access etc. should involve persisted state. (loaded & persisted in pre-render pass where UI decisions done in the 2nd finalized pass) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerender?view=aspnetcore-8.0#persist-prerendered-state
